# Run powershell script from cmd with admin privileges

Tags: powershell, cmd, admin

I am running a powershell script from cmd and I want to run it with admin rights.

```
powershell -command "&{. D:\Temp\Untitled1.ps1 ; Method1 'argument1'}"
```

Since I am not using start-process so I cannot use `-verb Runas`, what are the other work arounds for the same?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you _can't_ use `start-process`, since that would be the usual way to do this?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, my arguments that are being passed  are actually build arguments being passed over from MsBuilds as a string. So it has alot of single and double quotes and adding escape characters is not feasible

Comment: "I am running a powershell script from cmd" - why? Just run your commands directly in PowerShell and dispense with cmd.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart he's running the command from MSBuild (code compiler) which has very limited options, native powershell is not available.

Comment: If native PowerShell was not available, then you wouldn't be able to run it as an executable.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart; I am able to execute my powershell script, I just want to run the powershell session as admin

Comment: One easy way to do this is to use a small tool I wrote called Elevate32.exe or Elevate64.exe from [http://www.westmesatech.com/files/ElevationToolkit1.zip](http://www.westmesatech.com/files/ElevationToolkit1.zip).